# Xcode6 IOS8 mapkit pins not showing

Tags: xcode6

i wondering if someone may be able to help me. I am new to xcode and im trying to build a basic app. i have followed this tutorial

http://rshankar.com/how-to-add-annotation-to-mapview-in-ios/

i have copied the source code directly, i don't get any errors or warnings, however when running the app the pin locations do not show. Im not sure if they are there ( just invisible ) or whether they are not showing at all. I can't seem to find the issue.

Would anyone be able to suggest what the problem could be?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

actually managed to fix this, turns out the coordinates were round the wrong way!!!! Noob error!! I would like to change the callout on the pins if anyone could shed some light on where to change the code on the tutorial.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To change the callout of the pins:

- make the class that has your map view implement the `<MKMapViewDelegate>` protocol
- set the `delegate` of your map view to that class (e.g. `mapView.delegate = self;`)
- implement `MKMapViewDelegate`'s `(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation` method in that class

something like this:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    // If it's the user location, just return nil
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;

    // Handle custom annotations
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[NAME_OF_CLASS_IMPLEMENTING_MKANNOTATION_PROTOCOL class]])
    {
        // Try to dequeue an existing annotation view first
        MKAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKAnnotationView*)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"AnnotationViewIdentifier"];

        if (!annotationView)
        {
            // If an existing pin view was not available, create one
            annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"AnnotationViewIdentifier"];
            annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;

            // set callout
            UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
            annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
        }
        else
        {
            annotationView.annotation = annotation;
        }

        return annotationView;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

On your map pins (which should be made from a class that implements the `MKAnnotation` protocol), you should be able to set the `title` and `subtitle` properties.